# In method collection update not reactive on client template

Tags: meteor

The template helper `.header` in this Meteor code is expected to re render the "updated" value of the property `headerLabel` when the server method `headerUpdate` runs but it is failing to show the newly updated value even though the collection has been updated with the new value.

What is the correct way to fix this? Thanks

```
Template.header.helpers({
  headerLabel: function() {
    var userId = Meteor.userId();
    if (userId) {
      Meteor.call('getHeaderLabel', userId, function(err, res) {
        if (!err) {
          Session.set('headerLabel', res);
        }
      });
      return Session.get('headerLabel');
    } else {
      return 'Please login'
    }
  }
});

// on the client
Meteor.subscribe('headerLabelCol', Meteor.userId());

//on the server
Meteor.publish('headerLabelCol', function(userId) {
  return HeaderLabelCol.find({userId: userId}, {limit: 1});
});

// Meteor methods
getHeaderLabel: function(userId) {
  if (userId) {
    var result = HeaderLabelCol.findOne({userId: userId});
    if (result) { return result.headerLabel; }
  }
}

headerUpdate: function(userId, headerLabel) {
  HeaderLabelCol.update({userId: userId}, {$set: {headerLabel: headerLabel}});
}
```

**edit**
I changed the server size publish as below, using the [reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) package as below for no avail.

```
Meteor.publish('headerLabelCol', function (userId) {
  this.autorun(function (computation) {
   return HeaderLabelCol.find({userId: userId}, {limit: 1});
 });
});
```

Comment: As `getHeaderLabel` is an asynchronous call, the `return` statement immediately following the `Meteor.call` statement is executed before the call returns. And, because you are using publish-subscribe, is there any need to use a method?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen Isn't the 'Session.get' in the immediate return following the 'Meteor.call' ensures the re rendering of the value when the callback finally returns to do its 'Session.set(headerLabel, res)'? and as to the use of pub/sub and use of method. Well, only to minimise security risks, minimise client side code revealing/tampering in addition to other points learned from the book discover meteor / meteor-methods-client-side-operations. However your suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: I tried out your code, and it works for me. I didn't use the `reactive-publish` package, in fact, it is unnecessary if you are using methods. In Meteor, a helper is called automatically if any reactive data source (`Session`, in your case), which it is using, changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Two Solutions

---

**Solution 1 - using Pub/Sub**

1. Publish `headerLabelCol` on `server`:

   ```
   Meteor.publish('headerLabelCol', function() {
       return HeaderLabelCol.find({
           userId: this.userId
       }, {
           limit: 1
       });
   });
   ```
2. Subscribe to `headerLabelCol` on `client`:

   ```
   Meteor.subscribe('headerLabelCol');
   ```
3. In your `Template.header.helpers` on `client`:

   ```
   Template.header.helpers({
       headerLabel: function() {
           var userId = Meteor.userId();
           if (userId) {
               var result = HeaderLabelCol.findOne({userId:userId});
               if(result) {
                   return result.headerLabel;
               } else {
                   return 'Not Found';
               }
           } else {
               return 'Please login';
           }
       }
   });
   ```

*Note*: you can update the `Collection` via `Meteor.methods` or `Collection.allow`.

**Solution 2 - using Methods and Session**

Your code works correctly when I tried it out. So I'm not sure what went wrong for you, here's how I would solve this problem:

Define the methods on both `client` and `server`.

1. In your `Meteor.methods` on both `client` and `server`:

   ```
   Meteor.methods({
       getHeaderLabel: function(userId) {
           if (userId) {
               var result = HeaderLabelCol.findOne({
                   userId: userId
               });
               if (result) {
                   return result.headerLabel;
               } else {
                   return null;
               }
           }
       }, 
       headerUpdate: function(userId, headerLabel) {
           HeaderLabelCol.update({
               userId: userId
           }, {
              $set: {
                   headerLabel: headerLabel
              }
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. The `Meteor.call`:

   ```
   Meteor.call('getHeaderLabel', Meteor.userId(), function(err, res) {
       if (!err) {
           Session.set('headerLabel', res);
       }
   });
   ```
3. You can call the above from either the `Template.header.helpers` (as you have done) or from within the `Meteor.methods` `headerUpdate`. Either will work, but I preferred to do it via `headerUpdate`, like this:

   ```
   headerUpdate: function(userId, headerLabel) {
       HeaderLabelCol.update({
           userId: userId
       }, {
           $set: {
               headerLabel: headerLabel 
          }
       });
       Meteor.call('getHeaderLabel', userId, function(err, res) {
           if (!err) {
               Session.set('headerLabel', res);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

This makes sure that the method is called every time the data is updated. So the `Session`, which is a `reactive` data source, is updated and the template helper is automatically called.

4. The Template helper:

   ```
   Template.header.helpers({
       headerLabel: function() {
           if (Meteor.userId()) {
               return Session.get('headerLabel');
           } else {
               return 'Please login';
           }
       }
   });
   ```
5. Initial call to `getHeaderLabel` Meteor method:

   ```
   Template.header.onCreated({
       Meteor.call('getHeaderLabel', Meteor.userId(), function(err, res) {
           if (!err) {
               Session.set('headerLabel', res);
           }
       });
   });
   ```

This will call the `getHeaderLabel` method initially, before the DOM is rendered.